# Finding the true statements about the boundary of a set

Tags: general-topology

Pick out the true statements:
(a) If $A$ is open, then $∂A$ is nowhere dense.
(b) If $A$ is closed, then $∂A$ is nowhere dense.
(c) If $A$ is any subset, then $∂A$ is always nowhere dense.

$∂A$  represents the boundary of a set

---

I am stuck on this problem and seeking your help.

Comment: I believe only $(c)$ is false.

Comment: I get no clue.this is a problem from a question paper which I have tried to solve by myself.Can you say how can I tackle this problem?Thanks a lot for your interest.

Comment: Process of elimination perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

As you might be aware, for any set $A$, the relation $\partial A = \partial (A^c)$ holds. Here, $A^c$ is the set-theoretic complement of $A$. Since the open sets and the closed sets are complements of one another, you should be able to see that there is a close relationship between statements (a) and (b). In fact, they are both equivalent. It is enough to decide if one of them is true/false, as the answer for the other will be the same.

Some more points you may be aware of:

- $\partial A$ is always closed, for any set $A$.
- To decide if a closed set, such as $\partial A$, is nowhere dense, you just need to decide whether it has an interior point.
- Another way of saying that a set $U$ is open is to say that it contains none of its boundary points, i.e. $U \cap \partial U = \varnothing$.

If you want to showthat an open set $U$ has nowhere dense boundary $\partial U$, then you should show that each point $p \in \partial U$ is not an interior point. Indeed, any neighbourhood of $p$ will meet $U$ (since it is a boundary point) and points of $U$ are not in $\partial U$ (see above), so $\partial U$ is nowhere dense. This answers (a), hence answers (b) as well.

(c) is false. I will leave you with the following hint: try to come up with an example of a set $A$ such that $\partial A$ is actually the whole space (hence definitely not nowhere dense).